# Bind List instead list c# linq From multiple source

Tags: c#, linq

i have my dto

```
public class DocumentForListDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmittedAt { get; set; }
    public List<AuditsUpdateForListDto> UpdatedDocuments { get; set; }
}

public class AuditsForListDto
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

and this code in my controller :

```
 var docs = await _repo.Doc.Get();
```

and i have this audit to save any action in database

```
var aud = await _repo.Audit.FindByPrimaryKey(Constants.Doc, documents.Select(x => x.Id).ToList());
```

and this mapper for map my doc to dto(content)

```
var contents = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DocumentForListDto>>(docs);
```

and this my foreach to bind from audit to contents (CreatedBy/CreatedAt && UpdateBy/UpdatedAt)

```
           if (contents.Any() && contents.Count() > 0 && audits.Any() && audits.Count() 
              > 0)
            {
                foreach (var content in contents)
                {
                    //Search here by create Action
                    foreach (var audit in audits.Where(x => 
                    Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(x.PrimaryKey, @"\d+").Value) == 
                    content.Id && x.Type.Equals(Constants.Create)))
                    {
                        content.SubmittedBy = string.Concat(audit.User.FirstName, " ", 
                        audit.User.LastName);
                        content.SubmittedAt = audit.DateTime;
                    }

                 }
              //Here I need to bind list of Updated By and Updated At But I try many times but I don't find the right solution

             }
```

i need to bind list of Updated By and Updated At i try with many logics but without success ??

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i need to bind list of  Updated By and Updated At i try with many logics but without success :(

Comment: The question is so vague, you need to specify more detail.

Comment: Add model classes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i do but how to use loop for bind it

Comment: @mehdi where is your map defined? If you're using automapper, you should have a call to Mapper.CreateMap somewhere. Can you find it?

Comment: @NickMurphy i don't use automapper in last content like CreatedBy UpdatedAt